# How To Install Yii2 Alpha In Windows using composer

Tags: php, yii2

i am using yii 1.0 in all my project. today i got news that yii 2.0 alpha version is released so i am trying to install it in my window 8 system. till now i have never setup yii 2.0 application in my system.

so i started installing it Using this official link. but now i stuck in problem..

i have install composer in system and run it and it's working..

and i am trying execute this command `"C:\xampp\yii>composer create-project c:/xampp/htdocs/basic/yiinew"` but getting error `Could not parse version constraint`..

now i don't know how to setup application using composer.. i have searched in google "How to install yii 2.0 in window" but i didn't get any usefull link..

can anyone suggest me now what all are step i have to follow to install it?

i am using php 5.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should to execute : `C:\xampp\yii>composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic c:/xampp/htdocs/basic/yiinew 2.0.0-alpha`

Comment: i need to create dir say yiisoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As *Ororuk* said, you should simply try :

```
composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic c:\xampp\htdocs\basic\yiinew 2.0.0-alpha
```

This will install package `yiisoft/yii2-app-basic` (`2.0.0-alpha` version) in folder `c:/xampp/htdocs/basic/yiinew` (composer will create this folder if necessary).

EDIT : You should access this app using `http://localhost/basic/yiinew/web`

Comment: getting this error Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\yiinew\views\site\index.php on line 5

Comment: Yii view files are not intended to be accessed directly, you should use **http://localhost/basic/yiinew/web**